# A question about Banach algebras: showing that $\operatorname{Sp}a \subset D_o \cup D_1$

Tags: banach-algebras

Maybe this problem be easy for a person that have study in Banach Algebra; please give me a hint.

Let $e=0$ or $1$, and $a$ be an arbitrary element in a Banach algebra $A$. Let
$D_o$ and $D_1$ be the disks in the complex plane of the same radius
$\|a\|$ centred at $0$ and $1$, respectively. Then $\operatorname{Sp}a \subset  D_o \cup D_1$.

Comment: $Spa$ is the spectrum of $a$? And are the disks supposed to be closed or open?

Comment: $Sp a$ means spectrum of a. And discs are closed.

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page, the Banach algebra has a unit $e$, and the spectrum of $a$ is the set $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\colon \lambda\cdot e - a \text{ is not invertible}\}$. Or are you referring to the spectrum of the operator $T_a \colon x \mapsto a\cdot x$? (Not that it makes much difference.)

Comment: Use `\operatorname{}` to get the correct spacing and font. Just writing `Spa` means "the product of variables named $S$, $p$, and $a$", whereas `\operatorname{Sp}a` means "an operator named $\operatorname{Sp}$ applied to $a$"

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: $\operatorname{Sp}a = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\colon \lambda\cdot e - a \text{ is not invertible}\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Theorem 3.2.3 in "Fundamentals of the Theory of Operator Algebras" by Kadison and Ringrose. Their proof is instructive and I would suggest trying to look at it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding the image; I hope it is "fair use" :)

Comment: I believe that it is - [from the US copyright office](http://www.copyright.gov/fls/fl102.html): "The 1961 Report of the Register of Copyrights on the General Revision of the U.S. Copyright Law cites examples of activities that courts have regarded as fair use: 'quotation of excerpts in a review or criticism for purposes of illustration or comment; quotation of short passages in a scholarly or technical work, for illustration or clarification of the author’s observations...'"